# A six digit number is formed randomly using digits $\{1,2,3\}$ with repetitions. Choose the correct option(s):

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, proof-explanation

> A six digit number is formed randomly using digits $\{1,2,3\}$ with repetitions. Choose the correct option(s):
>
> - A) Probability that all digits are used at least once is $\dfrac{20}{27}$
> - B) Probability that digit $1$ is used odd number of times and $2$ is used even number of times is $\dfrac{1-3^{-6}}4$
> - C) Probability that all digits are used as well as odd digits are used odd number of times and even digit is used even number of times is $\dfrac{3^6-2^7+1}{4\cdot3^6}$

Total cases = $3^6$

- A) All digits used at least once = Total cases$-$Cases when one digit is not used

Or, would it be

All digits used at least once = Total cases$-$Cases when one digit is not used$-$Cases when two digits are not used

In any case, I am not getting $\frac{20}{27}$

- B) $1$ can be used $1$ or $3$ or $5$ times. $2$ can be used $0$ or $2$ or $4$ times.

So, favorable cases=$^6C_1(^5C_0+^5C_2+^5C_4)+^6C_3(^3C_0+^3C_2)+^6C_5=182$, and it matches with the answer.

But the answer given in the option is of different format $\dfrac{3^6-1}{4\cdot3^6}$. Looks like they are subtacting $1$ from the total cases and diving by $4$ to get the favorable case. Why?

- C) $1$ can be used $1$ or $3$ or $5$ times. $2$ can be used $2$ or $4$ times.

So, favorable cases=$^6C_1(^5C_2+^5C_4)+^6C_3(^3C_2)+^6C_5=156$

But as per the option, favorable cases= $150.5$. Also, looks like they are subtracting $2^7-1$ from total cases and then diving by $4$, what could be the motivation for this, even if this is wrong?

Comment: please let me know if you have any question on how to get to third answer from second

Comment: @MathLover thank you. I'll get back to it in a few hours.

Comment: Personally, I see no *intuitive* relationship between the form of their answers and *my computations*.  It could be that part of the challenge is to numerically check your calculation against theirs, in each of the 3 parts.  Note that in Part (C), their math is wrong only because the last term in the numerator is $(+1)$ rather than $(-1)$.  For what it's worth, in situations like those in Parts (B) or (C), where the cases to be examined are small, my first approach is to *forgo elegance* and just *manually compute* the right answers.

Comment: @user2661923 I think I found the approach to match the format of the options. I have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For the first**, it is application of Principle of Inclusion Exclusion or we can simply work as follows -

Total count of $6$ digit numbers $ = 3^6$

Count of numbers where one of the digits is missing $ = 3 \cdot (2^6 - 2)$

Count of numbers where two digits are missing $ = 3$

So the answer for $(a)$ is $ = \dfrac{3^6 - 3 \cdot 2^6 + 3}{3^6} = \dfrac{20}{27}$

**For the second**, your working is correct but another way to solve it would be,

Count of $6$ digit numbers where $1$ appears odd number of times and $2$ appears even number of times,

$ \displaystyle {6 \choose 1}\frac{2^5}{2} + {6 \choose 3}\frac{2^3}{2} + {6 \choose 5} = 182$

Explanation: Take the first term where $1$ occurs once. We choose a place for it from $6$ digits. Rest $5$ digits are made up of $2$ and $3$. In half of the numbers, $2$ will occur even number of times $(0, 2, 4$ times) and in other half it will occur odd number of times $(1, 3, 5$ times). Similarly other terms.

Now given first and second are correct. It must be third that is incorrect. Now notice that the third is a subset of second. In second, as $1$ occurs odd number of times, $2$ occurs even number of times and so $3$ occurs odd number of times. But in third, we need to subtract cases from second where $2$ was missing (occurred zero times). Can you take it from here?

Comment: +1 especially for the way you did the second part,

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore thank you!

Comment: @aarbee let me know if you have any question on how to quickly get to third from second.

Comment: Your comment to aarbee won't be delivered, because he has not *registered* for your answer, by leaving a comment.  Therefore, to address a comment to him, the comment must follow his question.

Comment: @user2661923 I think OP gets notified by default? No?

Comment: I am unsure, you could be right.  The way that I read the Help-Addressing article is that since the OP doesn't *own* the answer, then the OP is not notified automatically.  Again, I could be mistaken about this.

Comment: @user2661923 sure, will check on this.

Comment: Third case : $ \displaystyle {6 \choose 1}\left(\frac{2^5}{2}-1\right) + {6 \choose 3}\left(\frac{2^3}{2}-1\right) = 150$

Comment: yes that is perfect!

Comment: Hi. I have posted my answer below. If it can be improved, please give feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Sure @aarbee. Can I do it in 30 mins or so?

Comment: no problem. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to your answer, for showing your work.  I agree that your analysis for Part B is correct.  My analysis is:

**Part A**
Use [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

$\displaystyle \frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},~$ with $\displaystyle D = \frac{1}{3^6}.$

$\displaystyle N = 3^6 - \left[\binom{3}{1}2^6\right] + \left[\binom{3}{2}1^6\right] = 729 - 192 + 3 = 540.$

$\displaystyle \frac{540}{729} = \frac{20}{27}$ 
So, the answer given for part (A) is correct.

---

**Part B**
Again, $\displaystyle D = 3^6.$

$\displaystyle N = \sum_{k=1}^6 f(k),~$ as described below:

$f(1) : (1)$ "1", $(0)$ 2's : $\binom{6}{1} = 6.$ 
$f(2) : (1)$ "1", $(2)$ 2's : $\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{2} = 60.$ 
$f(3) : (1)$ "1", $(4)$ 2's : $\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{4} = 30.$ 
$f(4) : (3)$ "1"'s, $(0)$ 2's : $\binom{6}{3}\ = 20.$ 
$f(5) : (3)$ "1"'s, $(2)$ 2's : $\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{2} = 60.$ 
$f(6) : (5)$ "1"'s, $(0)$ 2's : $\binom{6}{5} = 6.$

$\displaystyle N = 182.$

$\displaystyle \frac{1 - (1/729)}{4} = \frac{728}{4 \times 729} = \frac{182}{729}.$

So, the answer given for part (B) is also correct.

---

**Part C** 
Again, $\displaystyle D = 3^6.$

$\displaystyle N = \sum_{k=1}^3 f(k),~$ as described below:

$f(1) : (1)$ "1", $(1)$ "3", $(4)$ 2's : $\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1} = 30.$ 
$f(2) : (1)$ "1", $(3)$ "3"'s, $(2)$ 2's : $\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{2} = 60.$ 
$f(3) : (3)$ "1's", $(1)$ "3", $(2)$ 2's : $\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{2} = 60.$

$\displaystyle N = 150.$

$\displaystyle \frac{3^6 - 2^7 + 1}{4 \times 3^6} = \frac{602}{4 \times 729} \neq \frac{150}{729}.$

So, the answer given for part (C) is wrong.

Note that if the answer given for part (C) had been 
$\displaystyle \frac{3^6 - 2^7 - 1}{4 \times 3^6}$, then the answer would have been correct.

Answer (score 1):

From @MathLover and @user2661923 answers, I got an idea to try to approach the solution in a way that would match the format of the options. So, here is my solution:

For part B), if $1$ is to come odd number of times, it would be $50\%$ of the total cases. And $2$ would come even number of times in $50\%$ of those cases. So, overall $25\%$ of the total cases. But here, we have also included a case where $2$ has come six times, and probability of that case is $\dfrac1{3^6}$. This needs to be subtracted i.e. $1-3^{-6}$. Now, taking its $25\%$, we get $\dfrac{1-3^{-6}}4$, which is the format of the option.

From this, we need to subtract those cases where $2$ had come zero times i.e. in those cases, only $1$ and $3$ could be filled. But we would consider only those cases where $1$ had come odd number of times, because those are the cases we are dealing with here. So, cases = $\dfrac{2^6}2$. Probability=$\dfrac{2^6}{2\cdot3^6}$.

So, the required probability for C) part$$=\dfrac{1-3^{-6}}4-\dfrac{2^6}{2\cdot3^6}\\=\frac{3^6-1}{4\cdot3^6}-\frac{2^7}{4\cdot3^6}\\=\frac{3^6-2^7-1}{4\cdot3^6}$$

Comment: Hello, are you there?

Comment: @MathLover yes.

Comment: For part (B), how did you arrive at the conclusion that there are equal numbers with odd count of $1$ and even count of $1$?

Comment: @MathLover Like the way you said, "In half of the numbers, $2$ will occur even number of times $(0, 2, 4$ times) and in other half it will occur odd number of times $(1, 3, 5$ times)". Isn't it the same here?

Comment: I was able to state that easily because I had a pre-condition that $1$ occurred once (or $3$ times or $5$ times), leaving odd number of digits for $2$ and $3$ so it is easy to see that half of the times $2$ has  even occurrence and $3$ has odd occurrence and rest half of the times, $2$ has odd occurrence and $3$ has even occurrence.

Comment: @MathLover If we have total $3^6$ cases, can't we say that in half the cases, $1$ would come even number of times and in the other half, $1$ would come odd number of times? Like, if we have just two places and two digits $(1,2)$. Then cases when $1$ is coming odd number of times is $12,21$ i.e. $2$ times. And cases when $1$ is coming even number of times is $11,22$ i.e. $2$ times. So, equal number of cases?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126240/discussion-between-math-lover-and-aarbee).

Answer (score 1):

I saw your question now and want to give you another approach. In my solution , i will use exponential generating functions.

$\color{red}{a-)}$ It is said that all digits must be used at least once ,so my exponential generating function will be $(e^x-1)^3 , [x^6]$ . As you see , it is binomal expression , so i can expand it like $e^{3x} -3e^{2x}+3e^x-1$ . Then ,we can write it like $3^r -3\times 2^r +3 \times 1^r$ where $r=6$

$\color{green}{b-)}$ It is said that  digit $1$ is used odd number of times and $2$ is used even number of times . Then ,we should their exponential forms  , so  that

Exponetial for $1=x + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120}$

Exponetial for $2=x^0 + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} +\frac{x^6}{720}$

Exponetial for $3=x^0 + x+ \frac{x^2}{2}  +\frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^4}{24}+ \frac{x^5}{120} +\frac{x^6}{720}$

Then , we are looking for the coefficient of the term $[x^6]$ in the product of the exponential generating fuctions such that :https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%281%2B+x+%2B+x%5E2%2F2+%2B+x%5E3%2F6+%2B+x%5E4%2F24+%2B+x%5E5%2F120+%2Bx%5E6%2F720%29%28x+%2B+2x%5E3+%2F3+%2B+2x%5E5+%2F15%29

We saw that its coefficient is $91/360$ .However , because of the fact that it is not in the form of $x^n / n!$ , we should multiply the coefficient with $6!$ . Hence , $720 \times \frac{91}{360} = 182$

$\color{blue}{c-)}$ It is said that all digits are used as well as odd digits are used odd number of times and even digit is used even number of times .

Exponetial for $1=x + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120}$

Exponetial for $2= \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} +\frac{x^6}{720}$ ,we subtract $x^0 $ , because it is said that each digit is used at least once.

Exponetial for $3= x  +\frac{x^3}{6} +  \frac{x^5}{120}$

Then , we are looking for the coefficient of the term $[x^6]$ in the product of the exponential generating fuctions such that :https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%28x+%2B+x%5E3+%2F6%2B+x%5E5+%2F120%29%28x+%2B+x%5E3+%2F6%2B+x%5E5+%2F120%29%28x%5E2+%2F2+%2Bx%5E4+%2F24+%2B+x%5E6+%2F+720%29

We saw that its coefficient is $5/24$ .However , because of the fact that it is not in the form of $x^n / n!$ , we should multiply the coefficient with $6!$ . Hence , $720 \times \frac{5}{24} = 150$

I think that exponenetial generating functions are the best for these types questions. I hope , it will help you..